# What do I need to be able to use Joomla as an online application development enbironment

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I develop applications using PHP and MySQL. They're not trivial, though they're not too complex. As an example to that I have written an online application to enable football administrators manage the player, competition and judiciary processes.

Separately to that I have used Joomla to create websites for small businesses.

I'd like to be able to use Joomla as my online application development environment. Is there a way I can use Joomla for that?

Comment: Can you be more specific, i.e. do you want use the underlying Joomla framework as a basis for your web apps or do you want to create external applications that link in or do you want to create extensions to Joomla?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. You will need to import the Joomla framework like so:

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/libraries/joomla/factory.php' );

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

You may need to change line 2 according to the location of your installed Joomla site